# Data Warehouse Opensource Tool for ETL

Tags: open-source, data-warehouse

Can anyone suggest me an open source data warehouse for Data Engineering Tasks where i can store data through ETL ingestion and train the model and save results.

Comment: Recommendation requests are off-topic for Stack Overflow as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but this might be on-topic for [softwarerecs.se].  But before asking there, check out their [on-topic page](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

you might want to check out caosdb (caosdb.org). it's a tool kit to put different data sources together and the ETL part should be covered well. the part regarding training the model, you might have to integrate another open source software into the tool.